# Custom List Form on Home Page

Tags: 2013, javascript, web-part, custom-list, form

I created a custom list in SharePoint 2013.  The question I have sounds simple but I have not been able to find a way that works.  I created a subsite and custom list.  When someone goes to the home page I want the form to appear on the home page.  I know I add a link to the new item from the custom list but I want the form to be on the page.  I was thinking to use page viewer web part.  that may display the form but doesn't allow someone to fill out the form.

Can anyone help me show the New Item form on the home page that will allow someone to complete the form from the home page and save.  Also I not access to use InfoPath.  That could be the easiest option.

Comment: Would you consider opening the form in a popup window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this earlier by copying webpart code to home page web part zone but ended with issues.
Then implemented a custom form and added to home page.

Here, there are 2 ways to do this.

1. Set new form as a home page and add additional web part zones to NewItem.aspx page (e.g.: right zone, left zone, footer zone, etc...) for other content.
2. Create a custom form using HTML and JavaScript and add to home page using content editor web part which we chose for our site.

Let me know if you need additional inputs.

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 1):

Customizing the OOTB form will consume more time, instead of that, we can create a new custom form as a custom web part.

**Step 1:** Create Custom visual web part

**Step 2:** Add Html, CSS, and jss whatever you required for your form

**step 3:** Deploy it your site collection, First Navigate to list/newform.aspx page and add our custom web part and close the existing OOTB web part(form)

**step 4:** Then add the same web part in Homepage(Handle it CSS\jss for the look and feel like to show the dialog based on icon click, etc)